# Sendkeys() not release the Element in Android App using Appium

Tags: android, selenium, appium

```
WebElementUserAccount=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc='User account']"));
          UserAccount.click();
          UserAccount.sendKeys("Test");
```

When I use this code it is not releasing the User account element it sends the text successfully but not came out of it 
In the second element, I have to send the password but it will not come out from the first Element

When I use

```
WebElement UserName= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc='User account']"));
WebElement Password= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc='Password']"));
UserName.sendKeys("UserName");
```

The Android keybord open before sending the text and it starts writing in the second element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `driver.hideKeyboard();` after entering text in your first element. Your keyboard might be hiding next element.

Comment: This won't work after enter the text in a first element it is not releasing the key

Comment: did you try it? if keyboard comes first then use it before 1st element.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do automation its better to turn off the text suggestion(predictive text) in the mobile keyboard.

Check whether the keyboard is displayed . If displayed use the following code:

```
driver.hideKeyboard();
```